# How to get data between 2 selected dates in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server

I have two dates, current date and previous date in yyyy-mm-dd format. Current date is today's date and previous date is 6 months prior to today's date. I've written a logic to display 6 months data by default but I want to change previous date and get data from previous date to current date so that if user is interested he/she can see data even before 6 months (say for example 7 months data or 1 year data). Please help me in writing this logic in Javascript. (no change in current date, current date is always today's date)

Comment: 1) Date is not in any format in database. Date is date format. You are viewing it as `yyyy-mm-dd` because of your client's settings. 2) How are you passing the previous date? Do you mean default value of previous date is `6 months prior`, but you want to override it to `n months prior`?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
select * from Tabel where DateColum between '2017/02/15' and '2017/05/17'
```

Comment: thank you, how can change pull records if i want to change previous date during run time?

Comment: Use jquery or javascript dom and on change event of the datepicker call the ajax to do the required operations.

Answer (score 0):

Use momentJS.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#submit").click(function() {
  var value = $( "#value :selected" ).val();
  var date = $( "#date :selected" ).val();
    var fromDate = moment().subtract(value, date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    var toDate = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    console.log(fromDate + ' - ' + toDate);
  });

});
```

```html
<!-- Include Bootstrap-select CSS, JS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://formvalidation.io/bundles/86618a522dcd0b92cc9a34866e45fa9e.css" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
  #bootstrapSelectForm .selectContainer .form-control-feedback {
    /* Adjust feedback icon position */
    right: -15px;
  }
</style>

  <div class="form-group">
<label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Value</label>
<div class="col-xs-5">
  <select name="value" id="value" class="form-control" multiple title="Select Value">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
        </select>
</div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
<label class="col-xs-5 control-label">Day/Month/Year</label>
<div class="col-xs-3">
  <select name="date" id="date" class="form-control">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="minutes">minutes</option>
            <option value="hours">hours</option>
            <option value="days">days</option>
            <option value="weeks">weeks</option>
            <option value="months">months</option>
            <option value="years">years</option>
        </select>
</div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
<div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-3">
  <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</div>
  </div>
```

Change the value of `subtract(6, 'months')` as per requirement.

**DEMO** https://jsfiddle.net/sumitridhal/97r1xd1r/

Comment: By default it should display 6 months data but i like to change previous date during run time. i am passing previous date from front end

Answer (score 0):

In javascript `Date()` gives current date.

For getting data between two date difference you simply create an object for two date.

```
var current_date = new Date(); //current date
var previous_date = new Date("yyyy/mm/dd");

if(current_date - previous_date > 0) //valid date range
{
     //your_logic      

}
```

> Note: If you fetch data from db then first check your database date
>   format and according to db-date format you pass your date in query
>   string

You want to change the date value at runtime then you need to get date from UI(if you have) or any other input mechanism.

For UI:  http://jsfiddle.net/GZ46K/

---

**UPDATE**

```js
function change(){
    
  var cur_date = document.getElementById('prev_date').value;
  var prev_date = document.getElementById('cur_date').value;

  if(cur_date - prev_date > 0) //valid date range
  {
    //your_logic      

  }
  
  //for test
  var title = document.getElementById('date_status');
  title.innerHTML = "Your Previous Date : " + prev_date + " Your Current Date : " + cur_date;
}
```

```html
<h4 id="date_status">Javascript date change example</h4>
<input id='prev_date' type='date' value='2009-11-11'>

<input id='cur_date' type='date' value='2009-11-11'>

<input type="submit" id="byBtn" value="Change" onclick="change()"/>
```

Comment: Take care in spelling JavaScript to avoid search-collision with Java.

Comment: Hello, thank you. Yes i am passing previous date from UI. By default previous date is 6 months prior to today's date but I like to change the previous date during run time, how to write logic for that? Please help me